# Are all parametrization via homogeneous polynomials rational curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Definition: A rational curve is a one dimensional projective variety that is birational isomorphic to a projective line.

If we have a curve $c:P^1 \to P^n, [x_0,x_1]\mapsto [f_0(x_0,x_1),...,f_n(x_0,x_1)]$ , where $f_i$ are homogeneous polynomials with same degree.

I've known that the imgae of $c$ is a projective variety and it's easy to see that there is a homomorphism from the function field of the image of $c$ to the function field of the projective line. But I don't know how to get the other direction to prove they are birational equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Let $C = c(\mathbb P^1)$ be the image curve. Then $C$ is rational if and only if its normalization $\tilde C$ is a $\mathbb P^1$. By the universal property of normalization, the map $c: \mathbb P^1 \to C$ lifts to a non-constant map of smooth curves $\tilde c: \mathbb P^1 \to \tilde C$. Such a thing only exists of $\tilde C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$, because whenever you have a non-constant map $C_1 \to C_2$ of smooth curves, then $g(C_1) \geq g(C_2)$ by Riemann-Hurwitz. Note however that $\tilde c$ need not be an isomorphism. (Find a counterexample!)